# Open source alternative to Truecrypt?

Tags: encryption, truecrypt

I was using Truecrypt to encrypt by work file backup (on Windows 7).
Now suddenly it's gone.

Is there any other opensource encryption software for free?

What are the existing Truecrypt users replacing it with?

Comment: Pick one you like: http://alternativeto.net/software/truecrypt/?license=free — there have been many articles covering TrueCrypt alternatives too, so please do a search. If you've run into a problem with one of these alternatives, it's fine to ask about that, but this question will just end up in a list of programs, based on opinions about what's the best one.

Comment: I just want to mention that TC isn't "gone". You can still download it from mirror and whatnot. The code audit is still going on. You can check its status [here](http://istruecryptauditedyet.com/)

Comment: slhck: I have been searching for the alternative for the past few weeks (naturally AlternativeTo and Google were the first places I searched) but unable to find anything nearly as reliable
@matan129: I am surprised that the audit is still on! as the Truecrypt homepage is saying that it's not secure anymore. And this is what came up today http://boingboing.net/2014/06/17/possible-hidden-latin-warning.html

Comment: Its real simple.  Truecrypt is one of the only cross-platform projects that offer disk encryption.  The only thing that has **currently** changed with Truecrypt is there will be no more versions released.

Comment: @Ramhound - the previous versions are available but there won't be any security patches, which are critical for a software this TC.

Comment: @matan129 - There hasn't been an update since 2012.  So for 2 years Truecrypt wasn't updated.  I don't see what has changed because the developers based on reports decided not to update Truecrypt to support GPT partitions.

Comment: @Ramhound - I cannot deny your statement, but I must say that the idea that an encryption software is unmaintained keeps me away from it.

Comment: I think it's a real question, as I can't find any equivalent of TC. why is this post 'put on hold as primarily opinion-based' ?!

Comment: https://ciphershed.org/ is a fork of truecrypt and is in active development. There isn't yet any release, but we can follow the development and try to compile it.

Comment: This is a real question (I hate StackExchange just getting good at removing blocking anything that doesn't look like a school textbook exam question) and there are two answers right now: [CipherShed](https://ciphershed.org/), https://www.grc.com/misc/truecrypt/truecrypt.htm, and [TCnext](https://truecrypt.ch/)